# Get Last file Commit Date from SVN

Tags: svn, command-line

Noob to Subversion, so please bear with me.

Is there a way to get the last commit date for a file from the command line?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
svn info filename
```

Comment: This will give the last changed info for the checked out <filename> which could be different from the repository file if you've checked out a specific revision/date. To be safe, give the URL of the file and you'll get the last changed info for the repository file.

Answer (score 4):

The following will show only the last changed date:

```
svn info --show-item last-changed-date filename
```

results in:

```
2019-08-09T10:48:22.754994Z
```

Answer (score 2):

`svn log -vl1 filename-or-url` will give you the commit log for the last change that altered your file.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to export only the last changed date.

```
svn info filename | grep '^Last Changed Date:'| sed -e 's/^Last Changed Date: //'
```

Comment: The same with sed only: svn info filename | sed -rn "s/^Last Changed Date: (.*)$/\1/p"