# SVN last write time of a file in SVN using powershell

Tags: powershell, svn, tortoisesvn

I know I can use svn list -v "SVN:URL/file.txt" to get a details of file. I'm looking to get the last modified time of the file and pipe to a variable where i can use further with powershell code.

```
svn list -v "SVN:URL/file.txt"
```

Comment: Is it what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798040/get-last-file-commit-date-from-svn

Then you can affect the final substring into the variable you want.

Comment: thanks .. @Yukirhodes i am looking for the same thing in powershell...,  the link has linuxcommands

Comment: What's up ? Did you unlock yourself ?

Comment: Thanks for your help ! @Yukhirhodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my first comment, you can adjust the Linux command to match the Powershell's syntax :

```
$yourvariable = svn info "SVN:URL/file.txt" | Select-String '^Text Last Updated:' | %{$_ -replace "Text Last Updated: "}
```

A few comments about this :

- Select-String is the equivalent of grep. It will return the matching line corresponding to the pattern you are looking for.
- %{} is an alias of a loop on the previous pipeline output (our line from Select-String). It is here because expressions like "blabla -replace 'bla' " are not allowed into associated pipelines (after | ), so we need to wrap it into something. Obviously, it is a single-pass loop.

If you want to retrieve another data, just modify the strings in the command (Text Last Updated, Path, Name, Last Changed Author, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

The following will show only the last changed date:

```
svn info --show-item last-changed-date "SVN:URL/file.txt"
```

results in:

```
2019-08-09T10:48:22.754994Z
```

So using the following should work:

```
$yourvariable = svn info --show-item last-changed-date "SVN:URL/file.txt"
```